# How can I assign course theming/layout to selected theme?

Tags: themes, moodle

I'm creating a new theme. Most of the default layouts should be changed. I want to change course weekly layout via my newly created theme `/theme/mytheme`. **For example** I want to add course participants on top of the layout. I explored the code and this is what I got: Htmls are created through some methods. So I should customize this via some files out of theme folder and that is what I'm not looking for.

Now my exact question: `Can I customize all moodle pages in my new theme? If yes, how?`

Answer (score 0):

For changing the weekly format and putting participants at the top of the course page have a look at creating a course format.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Course_formats or `/course/format/README.txt`

Create a `lib.php` file, extend the weekly format and override the output.

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . /course/format/weeks/lib.php');
class format_myformat extends format_weeks
    ...
```

Then select the format in the course settings.

Comment: So you claim that theming can not be fulfilled in `/theme/mytheme` folder And I am to edit some other moodle scripts, arn't you?